# Displaying field twice in same node

Tags: 7, entities

I want to have two styles of a specific field. How can I display the field twice so I can style each one differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside *node.tpl.php* instead of printing the whole content you can print fields seperately:

`<?php print render($content['field_name']); ?>`

Comment: I tried but didn't display anything

Comment: Is the field set to visible in `admin/structure/types/manage/[your-content-type]/display`?

Comment: Yes. I think its a problem with printing the same field twice?

Comment: You can print the field as many as you want. Where are you printing the field? Teaser or full?

Comment: Full  node display

Comment: Hmm. I think I figured it out. Node.tpl is used for teaser rendering.